# Fabric.io usertimeline loaded event

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, fabric.io

I'm using a Twitter feed from Fabric.io,.

To set up, I'm using this method:

```
final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
    .screenName(screenname)
    .build();
final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(mContext, userTimeline);
listViewTweets.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My goal is to show a loading indicator until the feed is loaded, thus shows in the view.
How do I do this?

Comment: "thus shows in the view" what do you mean ?

Comment: When the feed is loaded, it is shown in the view. When it is not loaded, there is nothing. When there is nothing, I want to show the user that the feed is loading, using a loading indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `listViewTweets.setAdapter(adapter);` insert:

```
listviewo.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.loading));
```

loading is a `ProgressBar` put it inside your XML where you have the `ListView`:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/loading_rotation"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

by this: `android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/loading_rotation"` i created a picture that rotate.

to set the animation just create an  `xml` file put it in a folder called `anim` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/iconloading"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" />
```

the loading picture is`iconloading`.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TweetTimelineListAdapter.registerDataSetObserver` to observer adapter changes and show a loading indicator while you wait for the initial data changed event.

For example in a ListFragment:

```
    public void onStart() {
        ...
        final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = ...
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {    
                setListShown(true);
            }
        });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setListShown(false);
}
```