# Resources$NotFoundException in anim folder

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, android-progressbar

I have created a anim folder under res folder in android studio. I guess creating the anim folder is fine under the resource folder. Now I am trying to put the file in the anim  folder and this is a file that is being used in progress bar.

But My app get crash stating the following line :

> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag sete

What I am trying  is to set the progressbar as the emptyview of the list view. 
so this is what I am exactly doing

**What I am doing**

**anim > loading_roataion**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    >
    <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/iconloading"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
    </set>
```

**my main_activity.xml**

```
///.....
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/loading_rotation"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
    ........
```

**and setting this in main activity like this**

```
customListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.loading));
```

But I do not know what is the problem . I am following all of that procedure from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849884/fabric-io-usertimeline-loaded-event) link.

Comment: I think this thing is creating problem
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    >

Comment: In which folder added `iconloading` Drawable ?

Comment: so what I need to do ?

Comment: @AllayKhalil: Problem is with `iconloading` as in Logs

Comment: you are right if you are thinking from log , I am updating the log now

Comment: loading_roataion or loading_rotation?

Comment: look now @ρяσѕρєяK............

Comment: @AllayKhalil: Is `iconloading ` is PNG file or any .xml file?

Comment: @SpiderMan its just typo mistake here in question

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK its png file  infact the drawable file

Comment: @AllayKhalil: ok in  loading_roataion.xml file remove set tag and use only `<animated-rotate>...` as in provided link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849884/fabric-io-usertimeline-loaded-event

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer it was quite easy I just changed it in the following way

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/iconloading"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="1080" />
```

and its working link a charm.